# Why can't I use reference types as the value type of a container type?

Tags: c++, stl

For example, `std::vector<int&> vec_int;` this seems to be invalid in c++. Why is this invalid?

Comment: you should rename this to "Why can't I use" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer, as per chryspi request above. As commented in other responses, you cannot use references directly as references don't exist by themselves.

You can use references, however, but by using the `boost::reference_wrapper<T>` utility class:

```
    typedef boost::reference_wrapper<int> intref;
    std::vector<intref> v;
    int i;
    i = 9;

    v.push_back (boost::ref (i));  // store &i

    int& j = v[0];
    j = 10;
    //v[0].get() = 10;

    std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 10
```

I put as an example how to modify directly the element `v[0]`. Note that it is somewhat tricky (you have to call the `get()` method) because you get a `boost::reference_wrapper<T>` instead of an actual reference.

For storing pointers safely with respect to memory, you can use `boost::shared_ptr` similarly.

Answer (score 9):

STL containers need to be able to construct objects with default constructor. You cannot do that with a reference. A reference is guaranteed to be valid, therefore it always has to be initialized with assignment.

You need to use a pointer instead.

Comment: There is another reason.  References cannot be assigned.  I believe that `::std::vector` requires that the thing stored in it be assignable.

Comment: Two notes here. One can use also `boost::ref` to store references in containers. And about pointers, also `boost::shared_ptr` to store them safely wrt. memory allocation.

Comment: Assignability is probably the culprit here. AFAIK, containers don't require default constructor, unless you call methods that use it (e.g `resize()` with the default and similar).

Comment: @visitor: Not right, you need default constructor in any case. It will fail as the templated methods need to be preprocessed in any case.

Comment: Sorry that's not right. It's not a requirement for `T` to be default constructible.

Comment: -1: You are wrong. The only requirement for T in vector<T> is that it be copy-constructible, which involved for T to exist a copy-ctor taking either T or T const & and that t have operator& with address semantics. Some operations on vector(like resize), however, require T to be also default-constructible.

Comment: "The default constructor is not required. Certain container class member function signatures specify the
default constructor as a default argument. T() shall be a well-defined expression (8.5) if one of those sig-
natures is called using the default argument (8.3.6)."

Comment: Thank you guys for clarification. I never got it compiled without default constructor at the point of creating the vector with gcc though.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, a `vector<T>` uses an array to store a sequence of `T` objects. Since references aren't objects, there is no such thing as an array of references (see 8.3.2 §5 in the standard), thus reference types cannot be used to parameterize the `vector` template.

What you probably want is a vector of smart pointers such as `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >` or a dedicated pointer container such as `boost::ptr_vector<T>`.